# Using AutoPep8 in pydev

Tags: python, pydev, code-formatting, autopep8

I'm trying to use autopep8.py as the code formatter for pydev but I don't seem to be able to supply the parameters correctly as the output isn't as I would expect.

I need to be able to supply two parameters `-a --max-line-length 100` but for some reason the formatter appears to be ignoring the line length option. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works for me. Have you enabled auto-formatting of editor contents in "Save Actions"?

Comment: Yes. It's enabled. I'm using Eclipse Neon (4.6.0). Not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: So does the formatter use the default value of 79 for line length?

Comment: Yes. That's what I see.

Comment: Do you modify the file before saving when testing the changed formatter settings?

Comment: I do. Usually not much more than adding a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm specifying the following settings and it works for me:

```
-a -a --max-line-length=100 --ignore=E309
```

So, I guess the problem in your case is missing the equals char after the `--max-line-length`.